# GENERATION OF CURRENT DUE TO ELECTRON FLOW

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electric-fields, electric-current, conductors

Why do flow of electrons generate current? whenever an electrons flows through a wire it generates electricity why does it actually happen?

Answer (score 3):

Current is by definition a flow of charge. Since electrons are charged particles, a flow of electrons is a current.

Similarly, since electron is charged, it creates an electric field around it, as all charged particles do. The flow of electrons is a wire is however usually a result of applying potential difference rather than the other way around. *Electricity* is not a well-defined notion, since it includes many different concepts and phenomena, so one cannot meaningfully talk about *generating electricity*.